# django application integrating pinning images

Tags: jquery, django, image

I am developing a **django** application.i want to integrate pin it functionality in my website.

ie, when a user drag a button(pin it) to any website having images.It displays all images in that

website and ask to pin it. when user click pin it, these images must be stored to db or

file-system of logged user.

Please help to integrate this .

Comment: First of all, I don't even understand your question. Come to think about it, it is not a question. Rephrase if you want an answer. Secondly it seems like you're asking for someone to write you a Django application? You would have better luck getting an answer by offering someone real money to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i apoligize for what i ask.

I did the pinning functionality successfully.

I designed a button with a javascript on onclick which redirects to a js.In that js i wrote function to capture the url of the current website and pass it to my view(ie django).This view will process this url and fetch all img tags(i used beautifulsoup to get all img tags). and display that img tags in a popup window. when user selects a img it will be added to my storage.

The users can add this button in bookmarks toolbar and whenever user want to pin images he can click this button.